# gimp python does not work: Failed to execute child process (No such file or directory)

Tags: python, windows, gimp

I don't know anything about python. I am trying to follow the most basic python tutorial where I just copy and paste text, save it as hello_world.py and save it in C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins. I've tried three different helloworlds. Nothing works, nothing happens. When I start gimp with --verbose I just get an error: "Failed to execute child process (No such file or directory)"

I am on windows 8.1 and I have gimp 2.8

Example of python that fails:
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/automating-gimp-scripts/

Why does it not work?

Comment: The .py file have the execution permissions? Can you also check if python is installed.